# Django + gunicorn + nginx Invalid HTTP_HOST header

Tags: django, nginx, отладка, gunicorn

Настроен сервер Django + gunicorn + nginx. `Debug = false`
Периодически приходят разные сообщения от Джанги, но следующее не понятно каким образом произошло. Пришло вот такое сообщение:

> "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: u'/путь_к_проэкту/run/gunicorn.sock:'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035"

Привожу ниже остальной код присланный мне на почту:

```
Request repr():
<WSGIRequest
path:/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '94.102.49.210',
    'PATH_INFO': u'/',
    'QUERY_STRING': '',
    'RAW_URI': '/',
    'REMOTE_ADDR': '',
    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
    'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
    'SERVER_NAME': '/путь_к_проэкту/run/gunicorn.sock',
    'SERVER_PORT': '',
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/19.1.1',
    'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x7f4ce037f2f0>,
    'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWraper object at 0x7f4ce0f59ad0>,
    'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper'>,
    'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7f4ce17f0550>,
    'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
    'wsgi.multithread': False,
    'wsgi.run_once': False,
    'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
    'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Comment: недопустимый заголовок. Если единичное сообщение - не стоит беспокоиться, просто редкое исключение, если частое - нужно смотреть при каком запросе возникает. Рекомендую установить sentry, там больше информации об ошибках да и удобнее, видно как часто ошибка повторяется

Answer (score 1):

из комментария:

---

Недопустимый заголовок.

Если единичное сообщение - не стоит беспокоиться, просто редкое исключение, если частое - нужно смотреть, при каком запросе возникает.

Рекомендую установить sentry, там больше информации об ошибках, да и удобнее: видно, как часто ошибка повторяется.